# how to make horizontal line between ::before and ::after element on hover?

Tags: html, css

My goal is to make horizontal line between The Anchor element, with ::before and ::after Pseudo Elements on hover.

The problem in my code is that horizontal line appears only on about element, when goal is to make it on every element. in developer tool it shows that properties are on every  element before and after but it only appears on one (about) element as I said.

Can you help me, how to fix this code ?

```css
nav,
nav ul {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /* justify-content: stretch; */
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-item {
  height: 8%;
}

.home-icon {
  padding-right: 0.5rem;
}

nav li {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  gap: 10px;
  height: 20%;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
}

nav li a {
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 1000;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: whitesmoke;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}

nav li a:hover {
  letter-spacing: 8px;
}

nav li a::before {
  content: '';
  width: 35vw;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  position: absolute;
  top: 35%;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

nav li a::after {
  content: '';
  width: 35vw;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  position: absolute;
  top: 35%;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

nav li a:hover::before {
  opacity: 1;
}

nav li a:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>

    <li>
      <img class="home-icon" src="./img/home.svg" alt="home" />
      <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="./img/disk.svg" alt="about" />
      <a href="#about">About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="./img/skills.svg" alt="skills" />
      <a href="#skills">Skills</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="./img/briefcase.svg" alt="briefcase" />
      <a href="#projects">Projects</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="./img/contacts.svg" alt="contacts" />
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I don't understand your goal clearly. You want that all links are underlined on hover of the navigation links, right?

Comment: @Lyokolux yes,  I want to underlined line on hover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were multiple problems with your CSS.

First off your were positioning your before and after absolutely, so they were always appearing in the same place. Second off, ::after and ::before are inline items by default so you need to set them to display: inline-block or the width won't take place.

I also took the liberty of reducing with width of your before and after since Projects is too long for 35vw on both sizes and would make the ::after appear below.

Code;

```css
nav,
nav ul {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /* justify-content: stretch; */
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-item {
  height: 8%;
}

.home-icon {
  padding-right: 0.5rem;
}

nav li {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  gap: 10px;
  height: 20%;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
}

nav li a {
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 1000;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: whitesmoke;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}

nav li a:hover {
  letter-spacing: 8px;
}

nav li a::before {
  content: '';
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 25vw;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  opacity: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

nav li a::after {
  content: '';
  width: 25vw;
  margin-left: 10px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  opacity: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

nav li a:hover::before {
  opacity: 1;
}

nav li a:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img class="home-icon" src="./img/home.svg" alt="home" />
      <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="./img/disk.svg" alt="about" />
      <a href="#about">About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="./img/skills.svg" alt="skills" />
      <a href="#skills">Skills</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="./img/briefcase.svg" alt="briefcase" />
      <a href="#projects">Projects</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="./img/contacts.svg" alt="contacts" />
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, it solve my problem... can you explain why position: absolute, act this way I mean appearing in the same place.

Comment: Absolute positioning means that an element will always be in the same place regardless of other elements. It is not affected by the positioning of other elements in the DOM tree.  You then use top, left, bottom and right to position the element. Top: 0 makes the element appear at the top, left: 0 makes the element appear on the left and so on. [Read more](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp).